# Let $f: X\to X$ be continuous map. Show that if $X=[0,1]$, there is a point $x$ such that $f(x)=x$. What happens if $X$ equals $[0,1)$ or $(0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: X\to X$ be continuous map. Show that if $X=[0,1]$, there is a point $x$ such that $f(x)=x$. What happens if $X$ equals $[0,1)$ or $(0,1)$?

**Here is my proof**: Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be continuous. Suppose neither

$0$ or $1$ are fixed points of $f$ because if they are fixed points, there is

nothing to prove. $f(0)\ne0$ and $f(1)\ne1$. Let $g:[0,1]\to[-1,1]$ be defined by

$g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then, $g(0)=f(0)-0$ or $f(0)>0$, $g(1)=f(1)-1<0$ or $f(1)<1$. By

the immediate value theorem, $\exists x\in(0,1)$ such that $g(x)=0$, which follows

that $f(x)-x=0$ or $f(x)=x$. Hence, there is a fixed point $f$ such that

$f(x)=x$ if $X=[0,1]$.

If $x$ equals $[0,1)$ or $(0,1)$, then $f$ can have a discontinuity at the

endpoints, so we cannot apply the immediate value theorem since we can't

find the values at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: For the second and third part: Just because $\neg P$ prevents you from using $P\to Q$ to show $Q$, doesn't by it self mean that $Q$ is false. In other words, you better exhibit explicit functions $f$ that are continuous and have no fixpoint

Answer (score 2):

Your argument for $[0,1]$ is fine. For the other two cases, however, you need to come up with explicit counterexamples. For each of them you could, for instance, let

$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}2\,:$$

clearly $x<\frac{x+1}2<1$ for $0\le x<1$.

Your statement about discontinuities at the endpoints doesn’t make sense: if one of the endpoints of the interval is included in $X$, then $f$ must be continuous there, and if one is not included, then $f$ isn’t even defined there and so cannot be discontinuous there.